# How to Group by Date Field in a PivotTable using win32com.client

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, vba, win32com

I tried many approaches from last few hours but no luck. Somebody please help me.

```
group_dt = pt.PivotFields('Created')
group_dt.LabelRange.Group(Start=True, End=True, Periods=Array(False, False, False, False, True, False, True))
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-0355ab1abb88> in <module>
      1 group_dt = pt.PivotFields('Created')
----> 2 group_dt.LabelRange.Group(Start=True, End=True, Periods=Array(False, False, False, False, True, False, True))

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I have figured out the way to group date field using win32com.client

```
cell = pivot_sheet.Range('B5')
cell.Group(Start=True, End=True, Periods=list([False, False, False, False, True, False, True]))
```